Error when using expand with Snakemake wildcards to aggregate across samples
I want to write a snakemake rule that aggregates across wildcards to produce a summary of all samples. It seems like a very simple case to me, but I cannot figure out the syntax error I am getting.
I used code found here.
Modified to look like this:
rule plot_coverage: 

    input:
            expand("{sample}.dedup.bam",sample=all_samples)
    output:
            "coverage_plot.png"
    shell:
            """
            echo "test"
            """

And get the following error:
"invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?:
    expand ( "{sample}.dedup.bam" , sample = all_samples )"

But if I use the same syntax to print a line somewhere else in the file it works fine and produces the expected results:
all_samples=["TN2L_S1","TN3L_S3","TN2R_S2","TN3R_S4"]  
print(expand("{sample}.dedup.bam",sample=all_samples))

Result: ['TN2L_S1.dedup.bam', 'TN3L_S3.dedup.bam', 'TN2R_S2.dedup.bam', 'TN3R_S4.dedup.bam']
If I comment out just the 9 lines of code shown above, along with the line asking for this rules output the rest of the file runs as expected without error.
Version information:
snakemake                 8.25.5               hdfd78af_0    bioconda  
snakemake-interface-common 1.17.4             pyhdfd78af_0    bioconda  
snakemake-interface-executor-plugins 9.3.2              pyhdfd78af_0    bioconda  
snakemake-interface-report-plugins 1.1.0              pyhdfd78af_0    bioconda  
snakemake-interface-storage-plugins 3.3.0              pyhdfd78af_0    bioconda  
snakemake-minimal         8.25.5             pyhdfd78af_0    bioconda  
python                    3.11.7          hab00c5b_1_cpython    conda-forge


Are you sure there are no other line after the expand, in the input section ? For me, this kind of error happens when I have several things in input, and I don't put a comma after one of them (except the last, for which it is not necessary). Also, make sure your indentations are consistent (preferably 4 spaces and no tabs).

I tried to recreate your error with the following minimal example (with three input files a.txt, b.txt and c.txt), but it worked fine. Does this work for you as well, and if so, could you tell us the difference to your code?
all_samples = ["a","b","c"]

rule all:
    input:
        "coverage_plot.png"  

rule test:
    input:
        expand("{sample}.txt",sample=all_samples)
    output:
        "coverage_plot.png"
    shell:
        """  
        echo {input}
        """  

